# I have a list of cost values that include "M" and "B" for million and billion. I want to create a new list that displays these values as numbers

Tags: python, list

I'm attempting to convert a list of monetary values which use "B" to mean Billion and "M" to use Million

```
cost=["1.2M","17B","79M","44.4M"]
```

I want to create a new list of float values.

The solution I can think of is using a dictionary:

```
convert={"B":1000000000,"M":1000000}

def updated_cost(cost):

 new_costs=[]

 for c in cost:

  /* do something*/
```

The area i'm struggling with is trying to figure out how to multiply the dictionary value and how to remove the "B" and "M".

Answer (score 2):

Yes, using a dictionary is a great idea!

```
string = "5M"
value = 0
convert={"B":1000000000,"M":1000000}

for i in convert:
    if i in string:
        value = float(string.replace(i, "")) * convert[i]

print(value)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also do it without using a `dictionary`:

```
cost=["1.2M","17B","79M","44.4M"]
new_costs = []

for elem in cost:
    if 'M' in elem:
        new_costs.append(float(elem[:-1])*1000000)
    elif 'B' in elem:
        new_costs.append(float(elem[:-1]) * 1000000000)

print(new_costs)
```

Output:

```
[1200000.0, 17000000000.0, 79000000.0, 44400000.0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Shorter way using a list comprehension:

```
cost=["1.2M","17B","79M","44.4M"]
newlist = [eval(x.replace("M","*1000000").replace("B","*1000000000")) for x in cost]
print(newlist)
```